# Is it allowed to publish app with similar name with other app by a different publisher?

Tags: android, google-play

For example, if I developed a run game but with different scene as temple run 2.  Is it allowed to publish the game with name such as 'Temple Run Fancy' in Google Play store?

Answer (score 0):

You can Host the application with same name, but package name should be different.

Comment: But today my app was removed from Google Play. Google said that the removal is requested by another company(developed a very popular game).  Reason for "Alleged trademark infringement".